# iAd App Network Discontinuation

Tags: ios, ads

I see this message when I sign into iTunesConnect:

"The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016. Although we are no longer accepting new apps into the network, advertising campaigns may continue to run and you can still earn advertising revenue until June 30. If you’d like to continue promoting your apps through iAd until then, you can create a campaign using iAd Workbench."

I have looked around at what it means and have seen multiple, very different answers.  What does it mean, exactly?  I guess questions I would like answered are:

1)  Will my current apps already in the store still be able to show/monetize iAds?

2)  Will new apps submitted before June 30th be able to use iAd for monetization?

3)  Will any apps submitted after June 30th be able to utilize iAd for monetization?

One answer I saw was that you can still use iAd and make money, Apple just isn't being the one providing the ads.  Another answer said that once this date rolls around, you can't use them at all, and you won't be able to make any money.  Basically they won't work.

Can anybody weigh in?

Comment: It's going away. Find a new ad network and refactor your projects.

Comment: Both answers are good, can you pick one as correct? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am developing a new app - not yet submitted, about to submit.

I emailed Apple last week to see if submitting a new app could still integrate iAds, hoping I could still use iAds until June 30, 2016.

This is the response I got:

> Hi Paul,
>
> Thanks for your interest.  After June 30th, the iAd app network will
>   no longer be available to help monetize your app.   No new apps will
>   be accepted into the network if you are not live already.  We have
>   campaigns live within our network up until that date.  You should
>   connect with another provider as an alternative to iAd.  Workbench
>   will still be available to promote your app.  Thanks for being a part
>   of our network.
>
> Please go to our developer site to get the latest news regarding iAd
>   here
>
> Best,
>
> Louis

This is pretty clear. NO new apps will be approved into the iAd network.

So, in response to your questions as listed:

> 1) Will my current apps already in the store still be able to
>   show/monetize iAds?

Yes, until June 30, 2016.

> 2) Will new apps submitted before June 30th be able to use iAd for
>   monetization?
>
> 3) Will any apps submitted after June 30th be able to utilize iAd for
>   monetization?

No. They will not.

Answer (score 1):

### What this means

After June 30th the ad network won't provide any ads to apps using it nor will you be able to start an iAd advertising campaign.

### Your Questions

1) 2) Current apps and apps submitted before June 30th can show and monetize iAds. When June 30th comes they will no longer show ads or make money.

3) Apps submitted after June 30th will not be able to utilize iAd monetization.

### What to do

Before June 30th integrate another ad network into your app if you wish to continue making ad revenue.

Comment: There is not going to be another one by Apple.

Comment: So primarily rely on admob now?